# isStretchWithOverflow not working

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm using a JasperReports, and `isStretchWithOverflow = true` doesn't appear to work; the resultant `.xls` doesn't have overlapped text fields.

## My jrxml

```
<detail>
        <band height="20">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" positionType="Float" x="727" y="0" width="90" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="33ce6f17-5af7-40ed-8b20-fec1a095e1f9"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{BarCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy">
                <reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" positionType="Float" x="817" y="0" width="90" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="fdf4bd37-5885-4e69-8890-3d5786538581"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DocDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" positionType="Float" x="907" y="0" width="80" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3692a8f5-a422-4fe6-8588-947b00512396"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DocNum}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" positionType="Float" x="987" y="0" width="131" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="0c8bb927-8993-4208-9aa4-34bf375591fc"/>
                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Accountant}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

## Picture of Result

[image: result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch overflow not working in excel jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593253/stretch-overflow-not-working-in-excel-jasper-report) & [Can JasperReports produce Excel file with column widths auto adjusted to contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1078717/876298)

Comment: its topics not help me

Comment: okey, its my decision.. `<reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="907" y="0" width="80" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3692a8f5-a422-4fe6-8588-947b00512396">
     <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
    </reportElement>`